# Solved Command Button not triggering Action Function

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Update**

It is creating the log. The actionfunction is working fine.

I'm not sure what is wrong with this. I've had command buttons trigger action functions before with no problem, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Earlier in the code I call an action Function from inside a script and it works fine. It saves the data to the controller that it needs to and every thing is fine.

When the button is clicked it should set the values and then call the saveData() function in the controller. It appears that it saves the data, I checked the log and it references assigning values.

However the saveData() function is never run. It should print a debug statement but it does not.

**Visualforce Snippet**

```
<apex:form >
            <apex:actionFunction name="savePar" action="{!saveData}" reRender="">
                <apex:param name="param1" assignTo="{!school}" value=""/>
                <apex:param name="param2" assignTo="{!schoolLevel}" value=""/>
                <apex:param name="param3" assignTo="{!birthDateStr}" value=""/>
                <apex:param name="param4" assignTo="{!address}" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>

            <input type="hidden" id="selStudent" style="width:300px" value="{!selectedName}"/>
            <div class="container">
                <apex:outputPanel id="fourm">
                    <div class="row" align="center">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>School Name</th>
                                <th>Grade Level</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><apex:inputText id="school" value="{!school}" size="30"/></td>
                                <td><apex:inputText id="grade" value="{!schoolLevel}" size="30"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" align="center">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Birth Day</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td><apex:inputText id="birthDay" value="{!birthDateStr}" size="30"/></td>
                                <td><apex:inputText id="address" value="{!address}" size="30"/></td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" id="do" 
                                onclick="savePar(document.getElementById('{!$Component.school}').value, document.getElementById('{!$Component.grade}').value, document.getElementById('{!$Component.birthDay}').value, document.getElementById('{!$Component.address}').value);" 
                                styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"/>
        </apex:form>
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
Public PageReference saveData(){
    system.debug('save');
    system.debug(stu);
    stu.Address__c = address;
    stu.Birthdate = birthDate;
    birthDate = date.parse(birthDateStr);
    stu.School1__c = school;
    stu.School_Grade_Level__c = schoolLevel;

    pageLoad();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct logs? By my calculations, you should be getting at least two logs per button click.

Comment: Any reason why you can't get those values from within your controller? It seems to me that it would be much easier that way. In your save method you would just get the values from the variables that are mapped to the input field tags, and then do your magic.

Comment: @sfdcfox You are right, it is creating two logs. It is running the code. I feel awfully stupid now. Thanks for the help.                                               
Renato The goal of the page is to allow someone to pick a student and modify basic information so I needed to pull in the data then overwrite it.

Comment: You can "return false" from your onclick if you want to avoid the second log entry. Realistically, this design is overly complicated, but this should get you going.